# How can I modify the keys in Django Auth ADFS claims mapping?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, azure-active-directory, django-authentication

I am using `django-auth-adfs` to authenticate Azure AD users on my django backend, this works fine for users within my organization. For users in other organizations however, there are certain keys defined in my `CLAIMS_MAPPING` that aren't returned in the JWT token.

I have tried different suggestions I found to get those keys to be present but non have worked for me, so I decided to just make use of the keys present in both tokens (tokens from my organization and tokens from outside my organization).

For example, I changed `'USERNAME_CLAIM': 'upn'` to `'USERNAME_CLAIM': 'email'` because the `upn` key is not present in both tokens but the `email` key is and they pretty much return the same values.

My problem right now is with the `first_name` and `last_name` keys. With tokens from my organization, this mapping works fine:

```
'CLAIM_MAPPING': {'first_name': 'given_name',
                      'last_name': 'family_name',
                      'email': 'upn'},
```

However the key `family_name` does not exist in tokens from outside my organization.

The `name` key exists in both tokens, so I thought to `.split(" ")` the `name` key and get the parts but I am not sure how to go about this since the mapping is to a string representing a key in the JWT token and not a python expression.

How do I go about this, please?